# javascript date - preserve timezone offset

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have a ISO8601 date that contains a timezone offset (see below). When I create a Date object from this, the date object is converted into my timezone (currently GMT), and timezone offset goes to 0. Is there any way to get the Date() constructor to preserve the timezone offset?

```
  var date = new Date("2012-01-17T12:55:00.000+01:00");
  console.log(date.toString());
```

The output I get is:

```
"Tue Jan 17 2012 11:55:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
```

The output I want is:

```
"Tue Jan 17 2012 12:55:00"
```

Comment: By copying & paste your example in Google Chrome, I get the output you want 'Tue Jan 17 2012 12:55:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)', which browser do you use?

Comment: @ArnaudF. I strongly suspect that is because your local timezone is GMT +1.  Here in Fort Worth, TX in Chrome I get: 'Tue Jan 17 2012 05:55:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not with the built-in [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), as they're only aware of ***Local*** (as defined by the user's browser and/or OS settings) and **UTC**. You can see this from the many cloned methods the class has (e.g., [`getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) / [`getUTCHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours)).

[`getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) is the only timezone info you really have, but it's *local* as well and will probably only give you `+0` again (or +6 in my case):

```
var date = new Date("2012-01-17T12:55:00.000+01:00");
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60.0);
```

You can try [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) (or [one of its forks](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js/network)), but you'll need to know the [Olson timezone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) not just the GMT/UTC offset:

```
var date = new new timezoneJS.Date('2012-01-17T12:55:00.000+01:00', 'Europe/Brussels');
alert(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60.0); // +1
```