# Javascript Timestamp formatting

Tags: javascript

Been trying to get my timestamp format as follows: `February 13, 2014 3:47 PM` (current time)

I know how to do the UTC and I know there is a way to do this using arrays for the months, but I was hoping to avoid building arrays and just a few simple methods...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of answers here on SO. One that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516995/create-another-formated-date-string-from-an-iso8601-timestamp/21518181#21518181 Otherwise look at a library like [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Xotic750 Right, I know that I can do it with array's and whatnot, but I'm trying to see if there is any way to avoid that.

Comment: What `new Date().toLocaleString()` returns in your machine?

Comment: Use someone else's work that is in a library and available publicly.